# how to turn vertex paint into texture

Tags: texturing

[image]ok so I am new to blender and I am trying to paint a mesh. I have found lots of people doing the same thing but my issues are different. I painted an amazing fox mesh using vertex paint. but when I try to edit or export the mesh it never exports the paint. I cant find out how to turn what I made with vertex paint into a texture.